# Go back from activity to fragment with Up button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

In main activity i've created two fragments used as tabbed menu. One of the fragments contains a list where list items starts a new activity when clicked. I wanna go back from new activity to the fragment (list) using the Up Action/Navigation button but no list is displayed, only an empty tab. I have declared parent activity as the main activity in manifest.xml.

When i use phone's back button it works fine.

List is created in fragment's onViewCreated method.

Manifest :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Fragment with listView which start the new activity :

```
 public static class frag extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER =   "section_number";

    public frag() {
    }
    public static frag newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        frag fragment = new rangingFrag();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listview);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.addAll(beacons);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                                                    int position, long id) {
                                                String selectedText = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                                bundle.putString("param1", selectedText);
                                                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                                                myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                                                startActivity(myIntent);
                                            }
                                        }
        );

    } }
```

Comment: add some code, it's hard to judge from the description. Did you set parent activity in manifest ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `Activity` where you want to keep the back arrow on the Action Bar, in `onCreate`, write:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And then override:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You can also use `setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);` just before `finish();`, to give the Activity you are returning to the ability to respond to the "child" activity finishing in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

You must define your navigation button as below

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // handle button click here
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED); 
        finish(); // close this activity and return to preview activity
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and hopefully it will work for you !

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
      Intent intentforBackButton = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
      intentforBackButton.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
      NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, intentforBackButton);
      return true;
       }
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```